# Doctrine Manytomany with additional field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I searchin everywhere something can help me to resolve this issue and did not find.

I have relation:

TABLE A --- one-to-many --- TABLE AB --- many-to-one --- TABLE B

ERROR what i get while try to call newAction method:

```
Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\Line#$buttons", got "AppBundle\Entity\Button" instead.
```

I think I have tried everything and get still same error.

Line entity

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Line
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="lines")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LineRepository")
     */
    class Line
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="line_name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $lineName;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ButtonsState", mappedBy="line", cascade={"all"})
         */
        private $buttons;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->buttons = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set lineName
         *
         * @param string $lineName
         *
         * @return Line
         */
        public function setLineName($lineName)
        {
            $this->lineName = $lineName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get lineName
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLineName()
        {
            return $this->lineName;
        }

        /**
         * Get buttons
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getButtons()
        {
            return $this->buttons;
        }

        public function addButton(Button $button)
        {
            if ($this->buttons->contains($button)) {
                return;
            }

            $this->buttons->add($button);
        }

    }
```

Button entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Button
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="buttons")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ButtonRepository")
 */
class Button
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="button_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $buttonName;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ButtonsState", mappedBy="button", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $lines;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get buttonName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getButtonName()
    {
        return $this->buttonName;
    }

    /**
     * Set buttonName
     *
     * @param string $buttonName
     *
     * @return Button
     */
    public function setButtonName($buttonName)
    {
        $this->buttonName = $buttonName;
    }

}
```

ButtonsState entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ButtonsState
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="lines_buttons")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ButtonStateRepository")
 */
class ButtonsState
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Line", inversedBy="buttons", cascade={"PERSIST"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="line_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $line;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Button", inversedBy="line", cascade={"PERSIST"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="button_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $button;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="integer")
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $state
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }  

}
```

LineController

```
/**
     * Creates a new line entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="line_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $line = new Line();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\LineType', $line);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            foreach ($line->getButtons() as $button) {
                $line->addButton($button);
            }

            $em->persist($line);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('line_index', array('id' => $line->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('line/new.html.twig', array(
            'line' => $line,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

LineType

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Button;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LineType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('lineName', null, array(
                'label' => 'Line name',
            ))
            ->add('buttons', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Button::class,
                'choice_label' => 'buttonName',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Line'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_line';
    }


}
```

Comment: Your `addButtons` method expects a `Collection` or an array, you're passing it a single instance: `$line->addButtons($button);` The fact that this method doesn't even exists in your pastebin leads me to believe this isn't the only problem.

Comment: I do not really understand. Expects a Collection?

Comment: `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` - it's basically an array with some extra functionality.

Comment: I’m sorry I had think about something else. I know what is an array collection but i dont know how to fix that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 51 of your Controller you are calling the method `addButtons`.

```
foreach ($line->getButtons() as $button) {
    $line->addButtons($button);
}
```

Try changing it to `addButton` since this is the method defined in the entity.

If this does not helps please provide the corresponding stack trace.

**Edit:**

Having a look at it again I've seen what the problem is.

You're treating the ButtonsState Entity as the table between an m to m relationship what it isn't since there's an extra property on it.

In the form type your'e saying that behind the buttons property of the Line entity there are Buttons. This is wrong. Behind this property there are ButtonsState entities.

So change your code as follows:

Form type:

```
// ...
->add('buttonsToAdd', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => Button::class,
    'choice_label' => 'buttonName',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'mapped' => false,
))
// ...
```

Controller:

```
// ...
$em->persist($line);
foreach ($form->get('buttonsToAdd')->getData() as $button) {
    $state = new \UserBundle\Entity\ButtonsState();
    $state->setLine($line);
    $state->setButton($button);
    $state->setState(0);

    $line->addButton($state);
}

$em->flush();
// ...
```

Like this you have an extra (unmapped) property whit the buttons on the form that you can convert to ButtonsState instances in the controller.

One more hint: use the command `bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:ButtonsState` to generate the getters and setters in your entities since they are wronc/incomplete at some places.

Comment: This mistake has been fixed before I post this, just forgot to change it on pastebin code. So I still get this (stack trace) https://pastebin.com/yRiYRiX8
And this is a dump before $em->flush; https://ibb.co/cjbosb

Comment: @Seven You should post your **actual code** in the question (not a link to a pastebin), if the pastebin link is not the actual code we're probably not able to help you with this.

Comment: Thank you very mach :) Works like a charm.

Comment: @Samuel Wicky Now I have problem with editAction, after go to edit page checkboxes are not checked and changes are not saving after submit form...

Answer (score 0):

## Add a 's' after line here:

**from**

```
class ButtonsState
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Button", inversedBy="line", cascade={"PERSIST"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="button_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $button;
}
```

**to**

```
class ButtonsState
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Button", inversedBy="lines", cascade={"PERSIST"})  // added a 's' behind line
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="button_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $button;
}
```

**Next time check your relations with:**

> bin/console doctrine:schema:validate